# how to check if a value already exist in db, and if so how to get the id of that row? android sql

Tags: android, sql, database

i have created the next db file -

```
String sql = ""
                + "CREATE TABLE "+ Constants.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + Constants.NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY    AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + Constants.NAME_PERSON + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
```

Now what I would like to know is, how to be able to run on the db and to know if a name already exist sin the db, and if so i would like to get the id of that row.

all i can understand is that i should use the

```
Cursor c= db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy)
```

but I don't have a clue what I should do next -
so thanks for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add this in your DB and call the function passing "to be searched key" as an argument

```
    public boolean checkIfExist(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_INFO, new String[] { KEY_TITLE}, KEY_TITLE + "=?",
                new String[] { name }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Where KEY_TITLE is the column name in your table.

Comment: That's it. You can simplify replacing `if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }`
by `return cursor.moveToFirst();`

Comment: what does [.moveToFirst()] gives me? and if i need an ID if it founds a simllier name. And what does[{new String[]] and [String[] { name }] stands for?

Comment: @4this this function checks whether an entry exist in DB or NOT

Comment: @Nitin Misra - few things - first of all mine query contains 7 diffrents inputs - your eight - why?. seconed of all  if i get it right by what u typed - i shohld enter - query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, NAME_PERSON, NAME_PERSON + "=?", [name that im looking for inside the name person colomn, null, null, null, null) - is that right?! and yet again isn't supposed to be 3 null at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Take more example on this:

[AndroidSQLite](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
[AndroidSQLite with multi tables](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

Make a SELECT request. Then check with `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` if your name is already existing. (`moveToFirst()` return true if there is at least 1 value).
So if your value is existing, juste get its id with `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));`